# Remove artifacts from OSM roads data in QGIS

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap

I downloaded OSM data for Amsterdam from the [bbike website](https://download.bbbike.org/osm/). Opening the roads layer in QGIS I get these strange artifacts where road sections cross the whole map in a straight line. What would be the best way to correct/remove them? Has anyone else had this effect with OSM data?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Same here, it seems to be an internal error in the postprocessing of the OSM data at bbike.

You can take the osm.pbf file from the same website, which works for me, or take the shapefiles from [Geofabrik](http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/netherlands.html) and cut out the area you need.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest first checking to see if the artifact lines share any common attribute that the others do not. If that is the case then select all features with that attribute and remove them.

Otherwise it seems like the artifact lines are very long so you could try selecting all lines with a length over a certain threshold and see if that snags the artifacts and not the genuine lines?

Also you might need to check if they are just single vertices which are out of place. If so the most accurate solution beyond finding better data would be to try and manually delete the incorrect vertices using the Vertex/Node Tool.